# How can I inject an intermediate branch?

Tags: git

After having modified the master branch of my repository, which I cloned from a public repository, I created a number of feature branches deriving from my modified master branch.

Now I noticed that my modifications to the master branch are unnecessary for some new changes I want to make.

So I want to revert my master branch to the originally, unchanged clone master. And I want to, instead, create an intermediate branch containing the changes I currently made to my master branch.

At the same time I want to keep my feature branches which I already pushed to the remote repository. (I already pushed my modified master branch, too.)

What are the steps necessary to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything at all, but if you do wish to do something, I'd recommend something different.

#### Background

In Git, branch *names* have very little significance to Git itself.  What matters are *commits*.  (The names are significant to *humans*, of course.)

Commits are uniquely identified by their big ugly hash IDs.  These seem random and are pretty useless to humans, so for drawing purposes, let's use single uppercase letters here instead.

You started with a clone with some series of commits, ending with a commit we'll call `H` instead of using its actual hash:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You then added several new commits of your own on your `master`.  Each one got a new big ugly hash ID, which we'll replace with the next letter:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The making of a new commit tells Git: *please move the **current branch**, i.e., the one to which `HEAD` is attached, to point to this new commit, which points back to its previoius commit.*  So now `master` names commit `I`, not commit `H` any more.  Commit `I` remembers the hash for `H`, though.  If you made two more commits the picture became:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master (HEAD)
```

It's at this point that you created your feature branches—so let's draw that:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master (HEAD), feature1, feature2
```

Then you selected one of those `feature` branches on which to create new commits, by attaching `HEAD` to it.  Let's pick `feature1`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master, feature1 (HEAD), feature2
```

Next, you created a commit or two:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master, feature2
                    \
                     L--M   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

Perhaps, next, you selected `feature2` as the current branch (via `git checkout feature2`) and created another commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master
                   |\
                   | L--M   <-- feature1
                   |
                    `--N   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

What you're asking to do now, for whatever inexplicable reason, is to make your `master` point to commit `H` again.  You can do that without any consequences at all to your own repository, by telling Git: *Move `master` so that it points to commmit `H`.*  The effect is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J--K
                   |\
                   | L--M   <-- feature1
                   |
                    `--N   <-- feature2
```

Commits `I` through `K` are now findable by:

- starting at the end of `feature1` and working backwards: `M`, `L`, `K`, `J`, `I`, `H`, ...
- starting at the end of `feature2` and working backwards: `N`, `K`, `J`, `I`, `H`, ...

Should you wish to remember, as a distinguished name, the hash ID of commit `K`, so that you can start *new* features from there, you need only create a *new* name pointing to commit `K`.  This new name can be a *branch name* or a *tag name*, whichever you prefer.

#### Your goal

> So I want to revert my master branch to the originally, unchanged clone master. And I want to, instead, create an intermediate branch containing the changes I currently made to my master branch.

The commit to which your `master` originally pointed is still in your repository.  It's commit `H`.  Of course, actual commit hash IDs are big and ugly—it's not really `H`, it's some impossible-to-remember long string of hexadecimal digits.  Unfortunately:

> At the same time I want to keep my feature branches which I already pushed to the remote repository. (I already pushed my modified master branch, too.)

When you ran `git push origin master`, you told your Git to send commits `K` and earlier if and as needed to `origin`—another Git repository—and then to ask the Git managing `origin` to set *its* master to point to `K`.  When it accepted this request, your Git updated your own `origin/master` to remember hash ID `K` instead of remembering hash ID `H`.  So at this point you have something more like this:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master, origin/master
                   |\
                   | L--M   <-- feature1
                   |
                    `--N   <-- feature2
```

If you remember *exactly how many* commits to count backwards from `K`, you can find `H` that way.  But if you did all of this recently—within the last three months—then your own Git *still remembers where `origin/master` used to point, three months or less ago*.  So you can just run:

```
git reflog origin/master
```

to see which commits `origin/master` *used to* identify, over time.  Add `--date=relative` to get date information, and you may find the logs to back much further than just three months.  Git can be rather lax about cleaning them out, and the 90 day expiry is just a limit: when Git gets vigorous about cleaning out old reflogs, it will throw out things older than 90 days (by default, or 30 days for some less-useful cases that won't apply here).

```
$ git reflog --date=relative origin/master
3c31a20 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) refs/remotes/origin/master@{51 minutes ago}: update by push
cf68824 refs/remotes/origin/master@{3 months ago}: update by push
...
ce4f7f9 refs/remotes/origin/master@{1 year, 2 months ago}: update by push
```

So to find `H` in *your* repository, try the `git reflog` command.

Having found `H`, you can just attach a new name to it:

```
git branch aha <hash-ID>
```

which will produce:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- aha
            \
             I--J--K   <-- master, origin/master
                   |\
                   | L--M   <-- feature1
                   |
                    `--N   <-- feature2
```

You can now *swap* `aha` and `master`, if you like, or do anything else you like, with these various branch names.  Just remember that if anyone *else* is using clones of your repository, or of your `origin` repository, those *other people* may be expecting that branch names only acquire *new* commits.  If you move a branch name "backwards" (to an older commit), those other people may become confused by this, and attempt to insist that you move the name forwards again.

Comment: Gee, Torek, sir, your explanation is AWESOME! Thank you so much! ... How would I swap branches then? ... Actually, I'm facing a similar issue with another repository now. I need to revert my master there, too. I guess that would be the same procedure? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174319/how-can-i-keep-my-git-history-tidy-even-after-rebasing-syncing-in-visual-studio)

Comment: To swap two branch pointers—let's call them A and B and say that A's stored hash is HA and B's is HB—just set the value stored in A to HB and then set the value stored in B to HA. Obviously you'll need to save at least one of these two values somewhere, e.g., perhaps obtain both up front on the screen before updating both, so that you can copy-paste the old values. To forcibly set some non-HEAD branch X to value Y, you can use `git branch -f X Y`, e.g., `git branch -f A B` sets `A` to `B`'s current value (and hence loses the old value of `A`). Setting the current (HEAD) branch is a bit harder.