# How can I keep my Git history tidy even after rebasing/syncing in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I don't have a clue how Git and Visual Studio Code get to generate their sync and commit history.

This is what I do:

1. I clone the `master` branch of some public repository.
2. In VS Code I add a few changes to some files, create a new branch and commit my changes by syncing.
3. A few weeks later, commits have been made to the public repository's `master` branch.

   So, I ...

   1. `git fetch` the public repository's master branch.
   2. `git merge` the public `master` branch into my local `master` branch.
   3. `git rebase` my local `master` branch to my local feature branch.

Doing so, Visual Studio code shows loads of upload files in the Sync panel:
[image]

When I then hit Sync, my feature branch's history is getting bloated with all the commits from others (plus mine, all over again):

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I retain a clean history, showing only my changes, even after rebasing to the public `master` branch?

The only solution I know so far is to make a local copy of my feature branch, delete my feature branch locally/remote and to re-create my feature branch anew. But this cannot be the only solution to this problem, can it?

### EDIT:

Here's the ref log:

```
0d1c3018 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
0d1c3018 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
0d1c3018 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
6603ced6 HEAD@{3}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/printable-doc
6603ced6 HEAD@{4}: rebase: _all.md files removed, .gitigore amened to exclude _all.md files from being checked in.
5c5981d1 HEAD@{5}: rebase: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
96792a0c HEAD@{6}: rebase: docs(config) document optimization.chunkIds (#2727)
d74520b3 HEAD@{7}: rebase: Revert "cacheGroups" (#2725)
5b45f87a HEAD@{8}: rebase: Update split-chunks-plugin.md
cf26894c HEAD@{9}: rebase: Update split-chunks-plugin.md
87933814 HEAD@{10}: rebase: docs(plugins): Add title to cacheGroups (#2227)
df10358b HEAD@{11}: rebase: docs(plugins) IgnorePlugin new syntax and options (#2721)
df53ddd3 HEAD@{12}: pull --tags -r origin printable-doc: checkout df53ddd3fc0e0658ff8fe26601e335d54084e843
36fd49c6 HEAD@{13}: reset: moving to HEAD
36fd49c6 HEAD@{14}: reset: moving to HEAD
36fd49c6 HEAD@{15}: pull --force: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
59f28dbf HEAD@{16}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/printable-doc
59f28dbf HEAD@{17}: rebase -i (pick): _all.md files removed, .gitigore amened to exclude _all.md files from being checked in.
2ff2238a HEAD@{18}: rebase -i (pick): CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
c0c24679 HEAD@{19}: rebase -i (pick): fix(misc) Fix yarn install on node v10+ (#2750)
33edd340 HEAD@{20}: rebase -i (pick): docs(devServer): add `writeToDisk` option (#2747)
289c7f96 HEAD@{21}: rebase -i (pick): docs(guides): Update installation npm script name (#2749)
a9478498 HEAD@{22}: rebase -i (pick): fix(config): Fixed a single word (#2748)
f4a9e0c6 HEAD@{23}: rebase -i (pick): Add documentation for `Rule.use` as a function (#2694)
9fcb8f25 HEAD@{24}: rebase -i (pick): document when optimization.minimizer is fn (#2743)
fa315806 HEAD@{25}: rebase -i (pick): docs(plugins): Typo uses -> used in internal-plugins.md (#2742)
b56fb3c1 HEAD@{26}: rebase -i (pick): d3 doesn't include a pkg.browser field anymore (#2739)
87cc015e HEAD@{27}: rebase -i (pick): docs(concepts): Update why-webpack.md (#2729)
13d0c33f HEAD@{28}: rebase -i (pick): Change requestRegExp to resourceRegExp IgnorePluginOptions in docs (#2730)
93b53d8f HEAD@{29}: rebase -i (pick): docs(guides): Update author-libraries.md (#2735)
f49704df HEAD@{30}: rebase -i (pick): Document that concatenation is enabled by default (#2505)
148c2a1c HEAD@{31}: rebase -i (pick): docs(config): Added information on settings stats colors (#2731)
e6e266b9 HEAD@{32}: rebase -i (pick): docs(config) document optimization.chunkIds (#2727)
9999b431 HEAD@{33}: rebase -i (pick): docs(devServer): Clarify devServer "open" option description (#1890)
bee9bd81 HEAD@{34}: rebase -i (pick): Revert "cacheGroups" (#2725)
cf19bb6d HEAD@{35}: rebase -i (pick): docs(guides) Refer to specific polyfill reference (#2726)
8fa9e909 HEAD@{36}: rebase -i (pick): docs: added more info for magic comments (#2707)
08901f4a HEAD@{37}: rebase -i (pick): docs(configuration): Add default for parallelism (#2481)
e7aad8cb HEAD@{38}: rebase -i (pick): Update split-chunks-plugin.md
c20d28a9 HEAD@{39}: rebase -i (pick): Update split-chunks-plugin.md
e63bb3db HEAD@{40}: rebase -i (pick): docs(guides): Update hot-module-replacement.md (#2418)
9cbb47d4 HEAD@{41}: rebase -i (pick): docs(plugins) splitChunks enforce doesnt make maxSize ignored anymore (#2687)
3b7972cf HEAD@{42}: rebase -i (pick): docs(guides): Small readme improvements, remove the word "simple" (#2671)
51f0d24c HEAD@{43}: rebase -i (pick): docs(API) Add error report introduction of loaders (#2231) (#2298)
dab61061 HEAD@{44}: rebase -i (pick): docs(concepts): Add a warning note for common errors when specifying rules (#2376)
dc1c5470 HEAD@{45}: rebase -i (pick): docs(plugins): Add example on how to tree shake locales from date-fns (#2524)
4381e398 HEAD@{46}: rebase -i (pick): docs(plugins): Add title to cacheGroups (#2227)
f85d79fa HEAD@{47}: rebase -i (pick): docs(guides): Fix naming consistence of runtime.js output (#2512)
4e21d67a HEAD@{48}: rebase -i (pick): docs(plugins): Specify all inputs to `cacheGroup.name` (#2719)
8671cf2a HEAD@{49}: rebase -i (pick): docs(plugins) IgnorePlugin new syntax and options (#2721)
2cf4fcaa HEAD@{50}: rebase -i (start): checkout 2cf4fcaa63db30b244ea1325a7f0746ef84656e4
df53ddd3 HEAD@{51}: pull origin: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
c1e40bec HEAD@{52}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/printable-doc
c1e40bec HEAD@{53}: rebase: _all.md files removed, .gitigore amened to exclude _all.md files from being checked in.
49901a1d HEAD@{54}: rebase: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
0d1c3018 HEAD@{55}: rebase: checkout master
496d4429 HEAD@{56}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
0d1c3018 HEAD@{57}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
0d1c3018 HEAD@{58}: rebase: checkout upstream/master
8518cbb5 HEAD@{59}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
496d4429 HEAD@{60}: pull --tags origin printable-doc: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
2cf4fcaa HEAD@{61}: commit: _all.md files removed, .gitigore amened to exclude _all.md files from being checked in.
92426f5a HEAD@{62}: commit: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
8518cbb5 HEAD@{63}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
8518cbb5 HEAD@{64}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
8cd26a9f HEAD@{65}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
8518cbb5 HEAD@{66}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
8cd26a9f HEAD@{67}: commit: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
d5d3979c HEAD@{68}: commit: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
8518cbb5 HEAD@{69}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
8518cbb5 HEAD@{70}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
79524b6d HEAD@{71}: commit (merge): MarkDownLint re-activated.
337b0581 HEAD@{72}: commit: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
8518cbb5 HEAD@{73}: reset: moving to HEAD~4
1bde1966 HEAD@{74}: commit: MarkDown lint re-enabled, comments added to MarkDown concatenation script.
11304c48 HEAD@{75}: commit: Chapter help pages will now be automatically generated on build.
7011075e HEAD@{76}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
8518cbb5 HEAD@{77}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
7011075e HEAD@{78}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
8518cbb5 HEAD@{79}: checkout: moving from printable-doc to master
7011075e HEAD@{80}: commit: MarkDownLinter disabled to be able to check-in changes.
f446769f HEAD@{81}: commit: CSS rules added for printing, script added to create chapter-wide documentation files from single files.
8518cbb5 HEAD@{82}: checkout: moving from master to printable-doc
8518cbb5 HEAD@{83}: reset: moving to HEAD
8518cbb5 HEAD@{84}: clone: from https://github.com/SetTrend/webpack.js.org.git
```

Comment: Hard to tell with the information you've provided. The screenshot doesn't help much because it only shows some avatars (github?), but no usernames. I'm not sure which one is yours and which ones come from the remote.

Comment: I believed it was clear from the avatars: I'm present in all commits. Yet, here's the PR URL: https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/2754#issuecomment-453459028

Comment: When you say you "git rebase my local master branch to my local feature branch" what exactly are you doing? You might be doing this backward. On the command line it would be `git checkout feature; git rebase master`.

Comment: I can't recall, I'm afraid. I already closed VS Code, so the history is lost.

Comment: "*In VS Code I add a few changes to some files, create a new branch and commit my changes by syncing.*" This sounds like you made changes THEN created a branch, which would be backwards. It's also suspicious that you'd commit changes by "synching". I don't know VS Code, just Git.

Comment: I leave the details how it's done to VS code. Yet, it looks OK to me. A new branch is created when I tell VS code to create a new branch. Then, in a second step, I commit my changes to my newly created feature branch.

Comment: because after rebasing you need to do hard push: `git push -f`

Comment: I just read that rebasing after creating a merge/pull request is discouraged (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing #"Reviewing a Feature With a Pull Request"). My most urgent challenge is: How can I get back to my original two commits and have my master back in track?

Comment: I added the `git reflog` output now to my original question. Perhaps this may shed some light on the details?